react native bug when pressing the physical button to go back always closes the application (android)
Hi I have a problem with a react native project, I am using react-navigation (bottom-tabs, native-stack) in conjunction with redux so that if the user is authenticated it renders a different navigation stack.
The error happens in all the screens without any particular configuration of each stack, when the back button/arrow is pressed which is handled with the navigation header, then the navigation is correct, but if the hardware button is pressed, in android, the app closes directly or minimizes because the app state remains,
I checked the installation and configuration of the dependencies and everything seems to be in order,
This is the configuration I have for navigation:
Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";  // this was added as part of a workaround described below


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector((store) => store.user);

  const navigationRef = React.useRef(); // this was added as part of a workaround described below

  // this was added as part of a workaround described below
  useBackHandler(() => {
    const navigation = navigationRef.current;
    console.log('use back handler called');

    if (navigation && navigation.canGoBack()) {
      navigation.goBack();
      return true;
    } else {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
      return false;
    }
  });

  const AuthStack = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "" },
            headerBackTitle: "Regresar",
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{
              headerShown: false
            }}
            name="Welcome"
            component={WelcomeScreen}
          />
          // more screens
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </>
    );
  };


const AppStack = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              borderBottomColor: "transparent",
              shadowColor: "transparent",
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
              elevation: 0
            }
          }}
        >
          //.... more screens
          <Tab.Screen
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
              tabBarButton: (props) => null
            }}
            name="Profile"
            component={ProfileScreen}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
        <NotificationConfig navigation={navigation} />
      </>
    );
  };


  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}>
        { user.isAuth ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{ gestureEnabled: false, statusBarStyle: "dark", statusBarColor: "white" }}
            name="Auth"
            component={AuthStack}
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              options={{ gestureEnabled: false, statusBarStyle: "dark", statusBarColor: "white" }}
              name="App"
              component={AppStack}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Environment
This is my environment configuration (output from npx react-native info):
System:
    OS: macOS 14.4
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 136.25 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.20.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.22 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.7.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2024.06.24.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /Users/../.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.5, iOS 17.5, macOS 14.5, tvOS 17.5, visionOS 1.2, watchOS 10.5
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 30, 31, 33, 34, 35
      Build Tools: 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 34.0.0, 35.0.0
      System Images: android-33 | AOSP ATD ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-33 | Google APIs ATD ARM 64 v8a, android-34 | ARM 64 v8a, android-34 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-34 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-34 | Google APIs ATD ARM 64, android-35 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2024.1 AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838
    Xcode: 15.4/15F31d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 17.0.11 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0
    react-native: 0.69.4 => 0.69.4
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found

Solution 1: Handling of hardwareBackPress event - did not work

This was implemented on the screen components.

As part of the solution a hook was implemented in the screens to handle the hardwareBackPress event inside a useEffect:
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MyScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  
  useEffect(() => {
  const backAction = () => {
    if (navigation.canGoBack()) {
      console.log('is going back') // this log not called 
      navigation.goBack();
      return true;
    }
  };

  const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
    "hardwareBackPress",
    backAction
  );

  return () => backHandler.remove();
}, [navigation]);

....
};

In the useEffect it is called when the screen is rendered, but the backAction function event is not called when the hardware back button is pressed in android (it was expected to print is going back.), so, after pressing the back button, the app is minimized (as if the home button was pressed).
Solution 2: use of the library @react-native-community/hooks - did not work

This was implemented in the main navigation component, where the NavigationContainer is located.

As shown in the main code the use of the library was implemented as follows:
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import { useBackHandler } from "@react-native-community/hooks";
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";

import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector((store) => store.user);

  const navigationRef = React.useRef();

  useBackHandler(() => {
    const navigation = navigationRef.current;
    console.log('use back handler called');

    if (navigation && navigation.canGoBack()) {
      navigation.goBack();
      return true;
    } else {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
      return false;
    }
  });

// some stacks...

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}>
        { user.isAuth ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{ gestureEnabled: false, statusBarStyle: "dark", statusBarColor: "white" }}
            name="Auth"
            component={AuthStack}
          />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen
              options={{ gestureEnabled: false, statusBarStyle: "dark", statusBarColor: "white" }}
              name="App"
              component={AppStack}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

In the same way as in the previous case the console.log('use back handler called') message was not printed.
